# How can I populate the same value on the below dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVwPl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3UfT.png)

I have here 2 viewbag in my controller

```
ViewBag.MyCategory = new SelectList(db.RecyclableType, "id", "type");
ViewBag.iddd = new SelectList(db.RecyclableType, "id", "type");
```

and a View

```
@Html.DropDownList("iddd", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.iddd, "SELECT ITEM TYPE", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("MyCategory", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyCategory, "SELECT ITEM TYPE", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

i tried to create a function like below but nothing is working

```
document.getElementById("iddd") = document.getElementById("MyCategory");
```

Comment: how can i change the value of a two dropdownlist at the same time

Comment: First get the selected text from `MyCategory` like this `var dropDownValue = $('#MyCategory :selected').text();` And then set `iddd` dropdown with its value `$('#iddd').val(dropDownValue).attr("selected", "selected");` Note: Try to add jQuery reference in the view

Comment: it returns the value but doesn't add in the dropdownlist.

after an event the #iddd dropdown empty selected.

Comment: I added an answer please review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery

1. First on change of `iddd` dropdown get its `value`
2. Set the value to `MyCategory` dropdown and set the attribute to
   `selected`

```
$("#iddd").change(function () {
    var value = $("#iddd").val();
    $("#MyCategory").val(value).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

**Note:** Add jQuery script file in head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```